# How do I add UL LI every two loops on while

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to add my `ul` & `li` every two loop.. Example

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
 <ul>
    <li> <?php the_title() ?> - <?php the_content() ?></li>
 </ul> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Let's say I have 4 posts and I want the result should be like this

```
<ul>
 <li>Title 1 - content 1</li>
 <li>Title 2 - content 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Title 3 - content 3</li>
 <li>Title 4 - content 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is that in wordpress? the syntax is broken there

Comment: @BookOfZeus Yes and syntax fixed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a counter variable (start =0) that increments at the end of each pass through the loop. Then at the beginning of each pass, test `if($counter%2==0){ echo "</ul><ul>";}`and put the first `<ul>` and last `</ul>` outside of the loop

Comment: It will be `<ul></ul><ul></li>` every single loop.

Comment: What he said is correct afaik, example: `for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    if($i % 2 == 0)
 echo "every second time <br />";
    echo "every time <br />";
}`

Comment: Then something is in the wrong spot (sorry, on my phone)...($counter%2==0) shouldn't be true on every loop

Comment: Yeah, sorry, thanks, I appreciated your example for the OP...I'd been responding to his comment

Comment: Stop using echo inside a loop. $str .= ''; and echo at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfUls; $i++)
{
    $result = '<ul>';
    for($j = 0; $j < $numberOfLis; $j++)
    {
        $result .= '<li>Title content</li>'; // Perhaps an array with the whole list $listContent[$i][$j];
    }
    $result .= '</ul>';
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Yeah, looks I guess so. He could always use sizeof() on the array though. It seems he found his solution anyways :)